# How do I overload the '==' operator between two different classes?

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading

I've read the tutorials on how to use C++ operator overloading but I'm still confused.

I have a `node` struct which is wrapped by `Node` (a wrapper class) according to the [Geeks for Geeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/operator-overloading-c/) tutorial it seemed that if I wanted to be able to say `n == N` then I'd have to define a `global` operator, and make it a friend of the class? I did that, and it still isn't working, I get this error

```
g++    -c -o main.o main.cpp
In file included from main.cpp:3:0:
node.hpp:25:29: warning: inline function ‘virtual bool Node::operator==(const Node&)’ used but never defined
         virtual inline bool operator==(const Node &n);
                             ^~~~~~~~
node.hpp:27:28: warning: inline function ‘bool operator==(node, const Node&)’ used but never defined
         friend inline bool operator==(const node n, const Node &nt);
                            ^~~~~~~~
node.hpp:26:29: warning: inline function ‘virtual bool Node::operator==(node)’ used but never defined
         virtual inline bool operator==(const node n);
                             ^~~~~~~~
g++ -o edit main.o node.o
main.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x128): undefined reference to `operator==(_node_str*, Node const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:5: recipe for target 'edit' failed
make: *** [edit] Error 1
```

Which makes no sense to me, because I defined the `==` function in `node.cpp` so it's not undefined as far as I know

Here's my code:

`node.hpp`

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <iostream>

typedef unsigned long int reference_counter;

typedef struct _node_str {
    reference_counter ref_cnt;
} node_str;

typedef node_str* node;

class Node {
    private:
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Node&);

    public:
        node n;

        Node();
        Node(node n);
        virtual ~Node();

        virtual inline node operator->();
        virtual inline bool operator==(const Node &n);
        virtual inline bool operator==(const node n);
        friend inline bool operator==(const node n, const Node &nt);
};

node node_create();
```

And then in `node.cpp`

```cpp
#include "node.hpp"

node node_create()
{
    node temp = (node)malloc(sizeof(node_str));
    temp->ref_cnt = 0;
    return temp;
}

// Node class definitions

Node::Node()
{
    this->n = nullptr;
}

Node::Node(node n)
{
    this->n = n;
    this->n->ref_cnt++;
}

Node::~Node()
{
    this->n->ref_cnt--;
    // TODO possibly check for and delete node upon count reaching 0
}

node Node::operator->()
{
    return this->n;
}

inline bool Node::operator==(const Node &n)
{
    return this->n == n.n;
}

inline bool Node::operator==(const node n)
{
    return this->n == n;
}

inline bool operator==(const node n,const Node &nt)
{
    return n == nt.n;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &strm, const Node &a)
{
    return strm << "Node Wrapper { " << a.n << ", Count: " << a.n->ref_cnt << " }";
}
```

And then a simple test `main.cpp` to use the equivalences.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#include "node.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    node a = node_create();
    node b = node_create();
    Node A = Node(a);
    Node B = Node(b);
    cout << A << endl << B << endl;
    cout << ((A == B) ? "A == B" : "A != B") << endl;
    cout << ((a == A) ? "a == A" : "a != A") << endl;
    cout << ((A == a) ? "A == a" : "A != a") << endl;
    cout << A << endl;
}
```

And the `makefile` to wrap it all together

```
CC = g++
objects = main.o node.o

edit : $(objects)
    $(CC) -o edit $(objects)

main.o : main.cpp node.hpp

node.o : node.cpp node.hpp

.PHONY : clean
clean :
    rm edit $(objects)
```

Would anybody be able to help me understand what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: In C++ you don't have to do the `typedef struct _node_str { ... } node_str;` dance. `struct node_str { ... };` makes the name `node_str` available without having to say `struct node_str` wherever you use it.

Comment: I tried to remove all `inline` then it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I overload the '==' operator between two different classes?

A typical solution is to 1. Make one type implicitly convertible to the other and 2. Make the common type comparable with itself using a non-member overload. It may not be a member overload, since that doesn't allow implicit conversion of the left operand.

Your attempt also works, but you've had to implement the same comparison three different times. My suggestion above works with a single overload.

---

> I get this error
>
> ```
> undefined reference to `operator==(_node_str*, Node const&)'
> ```

Problem is that you declared the function inline, but failed to define the function in all translation units where you called the function. In particular, you defined them only in `node.cpp`, but call them in `main.cpp`. The compiler warned about doing this:

> ```
> warning: inline function ‘virtual bool Node::operator==(const Node&)’
>     used but never defined
> ```

Either define the functions in the header or do not declare them inline.

Comment: Judging from how small the operator functions are, I decided to put them in the header file, since they could take adequate advantage of inlining

Comment: @iggy12345 that's sound reasoning.